# `time.sleep` in python script reading serial output causes erratic behavior

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, communication, python

I am attempting to control the position of my computer's cursor using a potentiometer hooked up to my arduino nano. The arduino is running the following code:

```cpp
int potPin = 3;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int val = 0;       // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(potPin);    // read the value from the sensor
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

When I ran the following python script, it worked properly and the sensor values were printing out in my terminal.

```python
import serial
import pyautogui

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbserial-141220", 9600, timeout=0.1)

while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode("UTF-8").strip()
    if data:
        print(data)
```

However, when I added a small time delay in the while loop, the output would either get stuck on a single value or take multiple seconds to reflect a change to the potentiometer.

```python
import serial
import pyautogui
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbserial-141220", 9600, timeout=0.1)

while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode("UTF-8").strip()
    if data:
        print(data)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I'd appreciate any help fixing this issue.

Comment: What is a small delay for you? 100ms? You are sending the values as fast as the Arduino can.

Comment: @chrisl the issue happens even with a delay in the python while loop of 10ms. I added the code with the loop to my question.

Comment: @ManavBokinala, Like chrisl said, you're sending as fast as you can.  What keeps approximately 9.6 characters per iteration from piling up in the host's inbound buffer?

Comment: You may find printing `ser.in_waiting` inside your loop enlightening.

Comment: @timemage Thank you so much, this solved my problem! I'm new to all of this, so I did not understand the concept of the inbound buffer. Your comment made things clear for me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to chrisl and timemage's comments, I figured out the issue: the Arduino was sending the data too fast and the bytes were piling up in the computer's inbound buffer. I solved this by adding a delay to the `loop()` function of the Arduino code.